# Set RemainAfterExit=no for a classic init script in systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, init

I run a custom service with a classic init script on Debian Jessie. Debian Jessie uses systemd. The reason that I use an init script is that I also use the same service on Debian Wheezy, which does not have systemd.

Since the service may crash occasionally, I want it to be relaunched when it stops. My understanding is that systemd will take care of this. However, when I manually kill the service (without `systemctl stop service`), `systemctl status` will report the service as `active (exited)`.

It is my understanding that this means that systemd simply considers the service to be one that can be "running" without having an process. [The documentation mentions `RemainAfterExit` as a way to configure this behaviour](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RemainAfterExit=), but this is a flag for use in a unit-file, I only have an init script.

Is there a way to let systemd know that an init service needs a process to be considered active? In other words, let it know that `active (exited)` is an undesired state?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by writing a generic boilerplate systemd unit file. Store the file in `/etc/systemd/system/$SERVICE.service`.

Replace `$SERVICE` with the service name.

```
[Unit]
Description=$SERVICE init script wrapper
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/$SERVICE start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/$SERVICE stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/$SERVICE reload
PIDFile=/var/run/$SERVICE.pid
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=always
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multiuser.target
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to refresh systemd's internals.